# Issues with using curl in shell script

Tags: shell, curl

When I try to use curl command in my shell script I get the following error message:  curl: (1) Protocol "http not supported or disabled in libcurl
When I use the curl command with the same http:// argument on my terminal, I get a response from the site. Am I missing something?

Thanks

**Update**

```
var4="localhost:8983/xxx?yyy";
var5="-F stream.url=nexus.cvs.ula.abc.html";
var6='"'$var4'" '$var5
curl $var6
```

Comment: Please provide the shell script that produces the error.

Comment: Please provide example of how you invoke curl in command line and inside script. Also I suggest to compare `$PATH` in both cases to ensure that you use same executable file.

Comment: var4="http://localhost:8983/xxx?yyy"
    var5="-F stream.url=http://nexus.cvs.ula.abc.html"
    var6='"'$var4'" '$var5
    curl $var6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error message

```
curl: (1) Protocol "http not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

makes me think that the URL you're passing may be

```
"http://someserver/somelink"
```

instead of

```
http://someserver/somelink
```

and curl is thinking that `"` is part of the url.

EDIT:

Based on your update, I'd say it should be:

```
var4="http://localhost:8983/xxx?yyy";
var5="-F stream.url=nexus.cvs.ula.abc.html";
curl $var5 $var4
```